# No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have component like this

```js
      constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.user);
        console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
      }
```

And i got when creating test like this

```js
    describe('OKComponent', () => {
      let component: OKComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<OKComponent>;
    
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [RouterTestingModule],
          declarations: [
            OKComponent
          ],
          providers: [
            {
              provide: ActivatedRoute,
              useValue: {
                snapshot: {
                  params: {
                    user: '',
                    id: ''
                  }
                },
                url: of({})
              }
            }
          ]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      });
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OKComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        TestBed.inject(ActivatedRouteSnapshot);
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

The error I got i always
**NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[ActivatedRouteSnapshot -> ActivatedRouteSnapshot]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot', 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot' ] })
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[ActivatedRouteSnapshot -> ActivatedRouteSnapshot]:**

I have looked all other solutions but nothing fix my error

Comment: You have ```ActivatedRoute``` under providers. Did you try to provide ```ActivatedRouteSnapshot``` explicitly?

Comment: This what you needed I think `TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);` Please try

Answer (score 1):

Like `JsNgian` said try `TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);` and you can get rid of this line because you're not assigning it to anything.

Try this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OKComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        // Delete the line bellow, you don't need it.
        // TestBed.inject(ActivatedRouteSnapshot);
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
```